# How can I run adb push or pull commands from an Android application?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, adb

Basically I want to transfer a file named sample.txt from by PC to my android device using adb push. This file should be transferred when I press a button from the Android application. For some reason the console in my eclipse is not working so I am displaying the content in the InputStream in the EditText itself. 
This code is executed when the button is pressed.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        try {
            EditText em=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            Process pro=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb push H:\\Android\\trasn\\sample.txt /storage/sdcard0/project");
            BufferedReader brp=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
            em.setText(brp.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run ADB commands from within Android. ADB is a desktop tool that allows for diagnostic interaction with Android, and those commands can't be run from outside of your desktop OS.

You'd need to set up some other method of communication between your computer and Android to transfer data - and some program on the computer would need to be expecting the communication. You can't just push files into any (most) modern operating systems.